# JSON parse in javascript vs. chrome console and eval

Tags: javascript, json

When I try to parse the JSON String below

```
'{"yearDuration" : "365","timeCapsule" : {"line" : { "entryDate"    : "1/1/2013", "exitDate"    : "12/31/2013" },"duration" : "365"}    }'
```

into a JSON object - I am receiving the following error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '
```

However, on the chrome=> developer console, when I do

```
JSON.parse('{"yearDuration" : "365","timeCapsule" : {"line" : { "entryDate" : "1/1/2013", "exitDate"    : "12/31/2013" },"duration" : "365"}    }');
```

I see that the JSON object is created -

[image: screenshot from the chrome console...]

But, when I tried using the eval method as explained @ the [link](http://www.json.org/js.html) it worked fine...

```
var presenceByYear = '{"yearDuration" : "365","timeCapsule" : {"line" : { "entryDate"   : "1/1/2013", "exitDate"    : "12/31/2013" },"duration" : "365"}    }';
var brktPrefixPresenceByYear= '(' + presenceByYear + ')';
var presenceByYearObj = eval(brktPrefixPresenceByYear);
```

Could some one help me figure out where I was going wrong with the JSON.parse?

Thank you

Comment: At my chrome(version 33.0...),there is no problem with `JSON.parse()` what is your chrome version?

Comment: same version. however, the problem is not with chrome, I am able to see the JSON object created in chrome - see link - http://i.stack.imgur.com/YFQou.png ... its during the javascript JSON.parse that I am getting the error.

Comment: You might try posting your code around line `270` in `main.js` as that'll help pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, I was constructing the JSON string with a set of variables and at the end

```
var presenceByYearStrPrefix = "'{\"yearDuration\" : \"" + 2013 + "\",";
var presenceByYearStrSuffix = " }'";
```

After some calculation in some loops and method calls -

```
var timeCapsuleStr = '"timeCapsule" : {"line" : { "entryDate"   : "1/1/2013", "exitDate"    : "12/31/2013" },"duration" : "365"}';
```

Finally, created the JSON String -

```
var presenceByYear = presenceByYearStrPrefix + timeCapsuleStr + presenceByYearStrSuffix;
```

Its only after I posted this question that I realized that I do NOT need the single quotes at the beginning of and the end of the presenceByYearStrPrefix  and presenceByYearStrSuffix variables as the concatenated value for presenceByYear is in itself a string.

Called the JSON.parse on the new variable values below -

```
var presenceByYearStrPrefix = "{\"yearDuration\" : \"" + 2013 + "\",";
var presenceByYearStrSuffix = " }";
var timeCapsuleStr = '"timeCapsule" : {"line" : { "entryDate"   : "1/1/2013", "exitDate"    : "12/31/2013" },"duration" : "365"}';
var presenceByYear = presenceByYearStrPrefix + timeCapsuleStr + presenceByYearStrSuffix;
```

and it worked like charm!!

Thanks for taking few mins in looking through this question!! :-)

Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid.

```
Parse error on line 1:
'{    "yearDuration
^
Expecting '{', '['
```

As per http://jsonlint.com/